# Delete directory in OS X from bash script

Tags: bash, macos

I want to run from bash script this command.

```
rm –rf secure_gate
```

But for some reason I get this error and I can't find why:

```
rm: –rf: No such file or directory
rm: secure_gate: is a directory
```

Do you know what is the proper way to delete directory in OS X?

Comment: Are you using the correct `-` character? In your question, it looks like you're using an en-dash

Comment: Yes, I suppose so.

Comment: @PeterPenzov: `rm –rf secure_gate/* ; rmdir secure_gate`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a hyphen in `–rf`, so Bash thinks that `–rf` is a filename.

If I [get the numerical value](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92447/bash-script-to-get-ascii-values-for-alphabet) of the dash copy-pasted from the question, I get

```
$ printf '%d' "'–"
8211
```

([en dash](https://unicode-table.com/en/2013/)) whereas a [normal hyphen](https://unicode-table.com/en/002D/) is

```
$ printf '%d' "'-"
45
```

Comment: `++` for a great observation. How did you manage to find that?

Comment: Well, the dash looks too long, and Daniel's comment was spot on - just verified it.

Comment: How I can fix this then? Just copy paste the symbol from the answer?

Comment: Do you have some weird key mapping? When you push the `-` key on your keyboard, it should very much produce a normal hyphen in your terminal and nothing else. Or did you copy-paste the command from elsewhere?

Comment: @PeterPenzov You fix it the same way you would had you type `rm =rf secure_gate`.